# MySQL in RDS is not throwing error for invalid datetime?

Tags: mysql, rds

I want MySQL should throw an error for Invalid datetime format, But it is not happening in my case.

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`userId`,`name`,`dob`) VALUES (DEFAULT, "Cane", "3000-60-99");
```

While executing above query below log will come out.

`1265 Data truncated for column 'dob' at row 1`

and the DB will contain the value :

`5, cane, 0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Describe users :

```
Field  | Type        | Null | Key |  Extra
-----------------------------------------------
userid | int(11)     | NO   | PRI |  auto_increment
name   | varchar(255)| YES  |     |
dob    | datetime    | YES  |     |
```

Comment: probably a typo but `dob`, should not have a comma at the end.

Comment: yes its a typo! corrected my error